# Pycharm: sharing objects with a notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

**Context**

I'm new to Pycharm and I've seen we can use Jupyter notebooks (aka Ipython) within Pycharm.

**Question**

If I use a Python script/console and a Jupyter notebook at the same time in Pycharm, is it possible to make them sharing the objects ?

Example :

1. From my python script I execute `a = 2`
2. From the notebook I execute `a`
3. It returns `2`

Comment: the short answer is no

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I am confused by your question, but can you not just use the "run" command in the iPython terminal to do what you are asking?

Say I have a python script named myscript.py. In that script, I define a = 2.

```
# This is myscript.py. It is located where you will invoke iPython
a = 2
```

If the script runs with no errors (hopefully just a variable declaration would :P) you should be able to do the following:

```
In [2]: run pythontest.py

In [3]: a
Out[3]: 2
```

If that is it, great! But I feel like I am missing some context to your question because that seems like it may be a bit too easy :).

Comment: I’d like to use both script and notebook at the same time and access in the the latest objects I created from the script in pycharm without executing all the script in the notebook since it would take time to recreate all the objects.

Comment: The only way I can think about doing something like that is using persistent storage. You can read more about it here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html. Essentially, you could use the above "run" command once, and then store your objects in iPython through the use of %store. This isn't a super clean solution and would require you to automate the storage of objects you wanted to keep to make it an automatic process (or just do it manually when you want to save), but it would give you a way to keep objects and update them as you go.